# Vector equation of a plane from normal vector and a point (quick way)

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

For example: the plane passing through the point $B(1,1,1)$ with a normal vector of  $(2i-j+2k)$

I know I can set up the Cartesian equation of the line, then find $2$ additional points on the plane by plugging random $x$'s and $y$'s into the Cartesian equation. Then setting up the vector equation by doing the standard method with three points.

However, is there any way to go straight to the vector equation without first having to set up the Cartesian equation and find three points?

Comment: use $\underline{r}\cdot\underline{n}=\underline{a}\cdot\underline{n}$

Comment: Which vector equation do you mean? The point-normal form or a parametric equation?

Comment: @RandomBob123 Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @RandomBob123 The version of your question which was posted in August is clear.  Please stop attempting to vandalize it and / or remove context.

Comment: Please do not delete questions with good answers. Others have devoted effort to answer your question and deserve the chance to get rewarded for it. Others may also benefit from your question and its answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the vector equation let find two vectors orthogonal to $\vec n=(2,-1,2)$ as for example

- $\vec v_1=(1,2,0)$
- $\vec v_2=(0,2,1)$

then the parametric equation of the plane through the origin is given by

$$t\vec v_1+s\vec v_2$$

then find $k$ such that $$t\vec v_1+s\vec v_2+k\vec n$$

passes through $B(1,1,1)\implies k=\frac13$ then the plane equation in parametric form is

$$t\vec v_1+s\vec v_2+\frac13\vec n$$

Comment: The OP asked for the vector equation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is: if $\vec n$ is a normal vector, and $80$ a point on the straight line, the equation, vectorially, is written as
$$\overrightarrow{M_0M}\cdot\vec n=0\quad\text{or }\;\overrightarrow{OM}\cdot\vec n=\overrightarrow{OM_0}\cdot\vec n,$$
i.e. with the present coordinates
$$2x-y+2z=2\cdot 1-1+2\cdot 1=3.$$